# A component is changing an uncontrolled input to be controlled for list of checkboxes in React Typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks, components

I have the component 'CheckboxWindow' that displays a 'CheckboxGroup' which is a list of checkboxes. An onChange gets called with the corresponding values (checked, value, i) for each checkbox. I am running into the error:

> A component is changing an uncontrolled input to be controlled. This is likely caused by the value changing from undefined to a defined value

when clicking a checkbox. I have already tried setting some initial values in the arrays as well as moving the logic in onChange() to a function inside the component but neither worked. Where is the issue exactly? Thanks

```
export const CheckboxWindow: React.FC<Props> = props => {
    const [selectedValues, setSelectedValues] = React.useState<string[]>([]);
    const [checkedGroups, setCheckedGroups] = React.useState<boolean[]>([]);

    return (
        <Window>     
            <CheckboxGroup
                    onChange={(checked, value, i) => {
                        const newGroups = [...checkedGroups];
                        newGroups[i] = !newGroups[i];
                        setCheckedGroups(newGroups);

                        if (checked && !selectedValues.includes(value)) {
                            setSelectedValues(prev => [...prev, value]);
                        } else if (!checked && selectedValues.includes(value)) {
                            setSelectedValues(selectedValues.filter(val => val != value));
                        }
                    }}
            />
        </Window>
    );
};
```